# Drawing Electrical Circuits using circuitiks

Tags: tikz-graphdrawing, circuits

I just need help with one specific portion of a electrical circuit. Also, when I put a battery on the circuit, it is drawed with two pairs of bars, not one like I want to. If you want, just tell me the commands then I'll figure it out myself. Thanks in advance!

I'll leave the tex code below for my attempt, and one image of the circuit (drawed with paint, please ignore the bad quality of the image of it).

The code:

```
\documentclass[article]{abntex2} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\title{Fisica III Lista 5} 
\author{Leandro Abib Mercês} 
\date{\ }

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle 
    \newpage
    
    \begin{circuitikz} 
        \draw (3,0) to[battery, l_=$\varepsilon$](0,0) ;
        \draw (3,0) to[resistor, l=5.0 $\Omega$] (6,0);
        \draw (6,-3) to[resistor, l_=5.0 $\Omega$] (6,0);
        \draw (0,-3) -- (0.5,-3) (0.5,-3) -- (6,-3); 

    \end{circuitikz}
    
\end{document}
```

The circuit:[image: That specific portion.]

Comment: the abntex2 class creates problem -- for me

Comment: Thats true, \newpage command goes as undefined control sequence. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Create a separate PDF using standalone or externalize (which also uses standalone).